# pyvisa gives errors but linux-gpib works

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, visa, gpib

I am trying to control an Agilent 33120A Arbitrary Waveform Generator using pyvisa under [Ubuntu 13.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_13.04_.28Raring_Ringtail.29) (Raring Ringtail). I have installed and set up everything that is necessary to communicate with the instrument using our labs NI GPIB-USB-B adapter. The adapter firmware is loaded, and so are the kernel modules from linux-gpib.

I can successfully do some dry-runs, e.g. by running `# ibtest` (command-line tool), I can write `*IDN?` to the device, and I receive the device ID: `'HEWLETT-PACKARD,33120A,0,8.0-5.0-1.0'`. I also tested other commands successfully, like setting voltage and frequency, and so on. It works.

The problem is, pyvisa always throws a `VisaIOError`... I have not clue how to get it to work. I run python-2.7 as root, so that (for now) I do not have to deal with any access privileges. This is the code and output:

```
import visa
>>> visa.vpp43.visa_library.load_library("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvisa.so.0")
>>> visa.get_instruments_list()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvisa/visa.py", line 254, in get_instruments_list
    vpp43.find_resources(resource_manager.session, "?*::INSTR")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvisa/vpp43.py", line 583, in find_resources
instrument_description)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvisa/vpp43.py", line 398, in check_status
raise visa_exceptions.VisaIOError, status
pyvisa.visa_exceptions.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_RSRC_NFOUND: Insufficient location information or the requested device or resource is not present in the system.
```

The library loads correctly. It is not even necessary, but I load the library explicitly to be safe. Obviously, pyvisa does not find any instrument. I also tried to explicitly open my instrument `board=0, pad=10, sad=0` using either of these commands:

```
visa.instrument("GPIB::10")
visa.instrument("GPIB0::10")
visa.instrument("GPIB::10::0")
visa.instrument("GPIB0::10::0")
```

But the same exception as above is thrown.

Basically, everything is set up alright, but pyvisa does not see anything.

Used versions:

- pyvisa-1.4
- python-2.7
- linux-gpib-3.2.20
- libvisa-0.0.20130812-1 (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/libvisa0/) newest build for [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) as this library is not in the repositories for Ubuntu 13.04)

I am hoping for some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyvisa` is a Python wrapper around NI-VISA. As far as I know it's not possible to use `pyvisa` with `linux-gpib`. But linux-gpib comes with its own Python wrappers. Simply `import Gpib` and you're good to go, for example,

```
>>>import Gpib
>>>device = Gpib.Gpib(pad=10)
>>>device.write('*IDN?')
>>>device.read()
'HEWLETT-PACKARD,33120A,0,8.0-5.0-1.0'
```

I guess you're writing some kind of measurement script. Have a look at [slave](http://slave.readthedocs.org/en/develop/#) it might be usefull for you (disclaimer: I'm the author of `slave`). It tries to simplify the device communication. Also it comes with its own wrappers for [linux-gpib](http://slave.readthedocs.org/en/develop/slave.html#slave.connection.GpibDevice).